# Browser javascript compliant system level js engine

Tags: javascript

All system level javascript engines(Node, Rhino, etc...) implement the **commonjs** specification that states that all code must be wrapped in an anonymous function. Due to this, experiments related to the context **this** does not yield the same results as they would in a browser.

For example, the following if run under node; would yield a different result than when it is run in Firebug:

```
var inner;

inner = 'inner';
this.inner = 'overriden';
console.log(inner);          // node: inner // firebug: overriden
```

For me, its more efficient to do these experiments in my *Ubuntu* terminal than in the browser. Is there a js runtime that can emulate the browser's runtime as it is in my terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [phantomjs](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs) to be most compatible to browser specific javascript.
. This could be probably because phantomjs is itself a headless browser. However it gives a commandline console and a way to run js scripts from the commandline.